# Create a List and Use it in Loss Function Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to create a list based on my neural network outputs and use it in Tensorflow as a loss function.

Assume that `results` is list of size `[1, batch_size]` that is output by a neural network. I check to see whether the first value of this list is in a specific range passed in as a placeholder called `valid_range`, and if it is add `1` to a list. If it is not, add `-1`. The goal is to make all predictions of the network in the range, so the correct predictions is a tensor of all `1`, which I call `correct_predictions`.

```
values_list = []
for j in range(batch_size):
        a = results[0, j] >= valid_range[0]
        b = result[0, j] <= valid_range[1]
        c = tf.logical_and(a, b)
        if (c == 1):
            values_list.append(1)
        else:
            values_list.append(-1.)
values_list_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(values_list)
correct_predictions = tf.ones([batch_size, ], tf.float32)
```

Now, I want to use this as a loss function in my network, so that I can force all the predictions to be in the specified range. I try to train like this:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(values_list_tensor, correct_predictions)) 
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
gradients, variables = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))
gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, gradient_clip_threshold)
optimize = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))
```

This, however, has a problem and throws an error on the last `optimize` line, saying:

```
    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['<tensorflow.python.training.optimizer._RefVariableProcessor object at 0x7f0245d4afd0>', 
'<tensorflow.python.training.optimizer._RefVariableProcessor object at 0x7f0245d66050>' 
...
```

I tried to debug this in Tensorboard, and I notice that the list I am creating does not appear in the graph, so basically the `x` part of the loss function is not part of the network itself. Is there some way to accurately create a list based on the predictions of a neural network and use it in the loss function in Tensorflow to train the network?

Please help, I have been stuck on this for a few days now.

Edit: 
Following what was suggested in the comments, I decided to use a l2 loss function, multiplying it by the binary vector I had from before `values_list_tensor`. The binary vector now has values `1` and `0` instead of `1` and `-1`. This way when the prediction is in the range the loss is 0, else it is the normal l2 loss. As I am unable to see the values of the tensors, I am not sure if this is correct. However, I can view the final loss and it is always 0, so something is wrong here. I am unsure if the multiplication is being done correctly and if `values_list_tensor` is calculated accurately? Can someone help and tell me what could be wrong?

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(tf.expand_dims(values_list_tensor, 1)), tf.expand_dims(result[0, :], 1))))
```

Thanks

Comment: apart from not being valid TF code, this loss makes no sense for gradient based methods as it is **non differentiable** (more precisely: it is differentiable, but derivatives are 0 everywhere, so no learning is possible). What you are looking for is something among the lines of L2 loss with "truncated" centre so that it gives 0 penalty in the range, and than l2 outside. Express it as an equation, not through ifs.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I am doing this as a kind of reinforcement learning reward based method, where the reward is +1 if it is in the range, -1 if it is not in the range. I then use this to update an LSTM. I will look at what you suggested in regards to the L2 loss. If you have code on how to do this and can post it as an answer and it works, I can mark it correct.

Comment: As a follow up, I want to only update the LSTM part of the network, I have some FC layers after this, and don't want to update that. I haven't been able to figure out the code yet. How do I consider the range as part of the `tf.nn.l2_loss` function? Should I create my own l2 loss equation?

Comment: I think the answer to my previous question is that I do need to create an equation, but I haven't found an equation that returns 0 if a value is in a random range else returns the normal loss.

Comment: @lejlot I made an edit to the original post, can you please check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the comment. One way to write a piece-wise function is using `tf.cond`. For example, here is a function that returns `0` in `[-1, 1]` and `x` everywhere else:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.cond(tf.logical_or(tf.greater(x, 1.0), tf.less(x, -1.0)), lambda : x, lambda : 0.0)
y.eval({x: 1.5})    # prints 1.5
y.eval({x: 0.5})    # prints 0.0
```